# Sorting imported text file?

Tags: python, sorting

So I've imported a text file into python. The file is a database storing users names and scores. It currently prints in pretty much the same format as the original file. I've split each line into two parts: name and score. I've managed to sort the data alphabetically, and am now trying to sort it from highest to lowest, but have no idea how??

```
file = open("classj.txt")
classj = (file.readlines())
for line in sorted(classj):
    classj = (line.rstrip())
    classa = (classj.split("-"))
    score = (classa[1])
    name = (classa[0])
    print(name,"-",score)
```

This outputs:

```
EMILY - 7
JEMMA - 9
LEO - 6
MARCO - 8
RILEY - 5
```

Any ideas how to make the code sort the file so the highest score (JEMMA) is displayed first, and the lowest score (RILEY) is displayed last?

Comment: Did you mean to write that Jemma has the highest score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the data as tuples in a list. then sort the list descending by score.

```
file = open("classj.txt")
classj = (file.readlines())
s = []
for line in sorted(classj):
    classj = (line.rstrip())
    classa = (classj.split("-"))
    score = int(classa[1])
    name = (classa[0])
    s.append( (name,score) )
s.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
for x in s:
    print(x[0],"-",x[1])
```

Comment: This would  only print the first one. You have to loop over all sorted tuples and print them.

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a list of tuples (name, score) of all the name/score pairs in your file. You can then use the sorted() function for lists:

```
import operator

ns_pairs = {"Emily": 7, "Jemma": 9, "Leo": 6, "Marco":8, "Riley": 5}
sorted_ns_pairs = sorted(ns_pairs.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

This is an example on a pre-defined list. You'd obviously want to create a list (like ns_pairs) by reading the names/scores in the file into the list. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Build name and score pair of list with `[x.strip().split('-') for x in open("classj.txt")]` and sort it with score in descending order.

```
from operator import itemgetter
for name,score in sorted((x.strip().split('-') for x in open("classj.txt")),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    print(name + '-' + score)
```